# how to read the variables in the format of long digits to R

Tags: r, csv

my question is I have a column which has such format as 20000000002185979. Everytime I read the csv file into R, it became "2e+16". So I can't distinguish from different values. Do you have any good ideas about how to keep the original format when read the file into R? Thx!

Comment: Wwll, technically it just displays as "2e+16". If you do `x<-20000000002185979; dput(x)` i'll see it has a few more digits. But that is a value that cannot be exactly represented by a `double` which is what R uses to store values. You may wish to read it in as a character.

Comment: @MrFlick thanks! So I should add an argument "colClasses", right?

Comment: Yes, with `colClasses` you can specify the data type for each column. Just use "character" for that particular column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it turned out to be the answer you wanted. I'll post it here to close out the question.

Since R is unable to maintain that many digits of precision with it's numeric values, you'll have to read it in as a character value. You can do that by setting the `colClasses` parameter of `read.table`.